# Hermitian matrix the only diagonizable

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, diagonalization, reflection

During the last lecture one of my professors claimed that the hermitian matrix is the ONLY complex matrix which was diagonizable.

This seems strange to mee (not to say a very very strong claim to make), I know that Hermitian matrices are the only ones diagonizable by unitary transformations, but that they're the only diagonizable ones seems strange.

Could someone elaborate on this ? Or provide some kind of proof for this ?

Comment: as far as I know, you may look for spectral decomposition on **normal matrices** first in which they can be unitarily diagonalized with complex eigenvalues along their diagonals.


For spectral decomposition on **Hermitian matrix**, the corresponding diagonal elements are real eigenvalues of the original one.

For spectral decomposition on **unitary matrices**, magnitude of elements along diagonal of the diagonal matrix must be one.

Comment: Isn't $A=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{matrix}\right]$ diagonal but not Hermitian, since $A^\ast=\left[ \begin{matrix} 1-i & 0 \\ 0 & 1-i \end{matrix}\right] \neq A$?

Comment: Diagonalizable over what field?

Comment: All matrices with distinct eigenvalues are diagonalizable, no matter what type. However, if the eigenvalues are degenerate, the multiplicity of eigenvectors may not be enough, if the matrix is not normal. It's also possible that he talked about unitary diagonalizability.

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://www.math.wisc.edu/~ellenber/Math204Lects/Week10.pdf

Comment: @GitGud, my fault over the complex numbers ? This claim was brought to me by a particle-physicist, so I think he might be looking for diagonizability with unitary matrices which is just true for the hermitian ones, right ?

Comment: @Hayden, beautiful ! I should have tought of that myself! Time to put that one in the professor's face and see what he has to say about that (in a polite way of course).

Comment: @Nick No. Hayden's example is unitary diagonalizable ($A=IAI$). Any normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable, though.

Comment: @Nick, as Git Gud points out, my example shows that it is not true that only the Hermitian matrices are unitary diagonalizable.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! To bad that there isn't a way to award you all with the right answer. Maybe looking at @Orion's source might help.

Comment: @Nick I would ask hayden to post his example as an answer.

Comment: Seems indeed toe most fair thing to do (since that comment hits tha heart of the question). So @Hayden, thanks for the great answer, if you'd likt to post it as an answer I can accept it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I'll provide my example and a little bit of exposition:

The claim your professor makes, namely

> All diagonalizable (in $\mathbb{C}$) matrices are Hermitian.

is false. Let us quickly recall what it means for a square complex matrix $A$ to be Hermitian: it means that $A=A^\ast$, where $A^\ast$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$,  A simple counter-example then is the following: $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{matrix}\right]$ which is clearly diagonalizable (it is diagonal already) but is not Hermitian because $A\neq A^\ast$.

Perhaps your professor meant to make a weaker claim:

> All matrices that are unitary diagonalizable are Hermitian.

Again, this is false, as the above example points out: $$\left[ \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{matrix}\right] =\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$  The identity matrix $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$ is indeed a unitary matrix, so that $\left[ \begin{matrix} 1+i & 0 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{matrix}\right]$ has a unitary diagonalization.

In general, the Spectral Theorem tells us that all normal complex matrices are unitary diagonalizable, and there are normal matrices that are not Hermitian.